# Tkinter create canvas that overlays screen with transparent background

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a canvas that overlays everything else on the screen using a widget without a window that is lifted with the `topmost` attribute.

However, I would like a transparent background.

Here is what I've got:

```
import Tkinter

vsize = vw, vh = 600, 350

w = Tkinter.Canvas(width=vw, height=vh, highlightthickness=0)
w.master.overrideredirect(True)
w.master.geometry("+0+0")
w.master.lift()
w.master.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
w.master.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
w.create_rectangle(0, 0, vw, vh, fill="black")
w.pack()
w.mainloop()
```

I tried adding the following attribute to the canvas and adding `stipple="gray25"` to the rectangle:

```
w.master.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "gray")
```

This for some reason didn't make the gray transparent, and even if this did work it would look awful using `stipple`.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I tried configuring the background as black, and giving it some transparency, but I would only like the background to be black so I can have non-transparent items inside of the canvas.

```
w.configure(background="black")
w.master.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.5)
```

Comment: You might want to look at Qt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950049/creating-a-transparent-overlay-with-qt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to achieve this in Tkinter I believe.

If you are looking for a way to overlay things on your screen, why not use individual windows placed on the screen? Else, I would suggest looking at other solutions outside of Tkinter.